# scalax.io._ Best way to overwrite data in file

Tags: scala, file-io

I have found that default way in write operations on file in scalax.io._ is "append".
But what the best and shortest way to operate with Resource.fromFile object for ovewriting data like system IO open(..,WRITE) call ? The Ideas that i have are deleting file or using seeking/patching API . but they to verbose for such simple operation .

```
scala> def mk(s:String) = { val out: Output = Resource.fromFile("/tmp/data");out.write(s)}
mk: (s: String)Unit

scala> mk("XXXX")
scala> mk("XXXX")

bash# > ls -l /tmp/data

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 8 Jun  1 16:27 /tmp/data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using plain old output streams:

```
import scalax.io.Resource
import scalax.io._
val out:Output = Resource.fromOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream("/tmp/testFile"))


out write "howdy"
out write "bah"
```

Be careful as file will be rewritten on each write.
See [daily scala](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2012/08/scala-io-core-output.html) how to overcome this, and for more examples

Comment: On existing file your solution dont work. It does not owerwrite full file in other words it does not truncate . Seems that docs are not uptodate or I dont understand a logic of author .

Comment: Yes, you are right previous solution didn't work. Updated my answer. You might want to follow the link to daily-scala as the author of scala-io posted there some very detailed tutorial.

Comment: How do we close the file after writing ? Thanks!

Comment: In this case it will be closed automatically. Again, see daily-scala, particlualrly this post: http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2012/09/scala-io-core-reusable-resources.html

Answer (score 4):

Truncate the file to zero-length using `truncate` from `scalax.io.Seekable`:

```
  val output = Resource.fromFile("/tmp/data")

  output truncate 0
  output write "Bigger on the Inside"
```