# Scala : Writing String Iterator to file in Efficient way

Tags: performance, scala, optimization, file-io

I have thousands of files (50K) and each file has around 10K lines.I read the file do some processing and write the lines back to an output file. While my reading and processing is way faster, the final step to convert the String Iterator back to a single String and write it to a file take a long time(almost a second.I wouldn't do the math for doing this for the whole population of files which is around 50K). I see this to be the bottleneck in the of improving my parsing time.

This is my code.

```
var processedLines = linesFromGzip(new File(fileName)).map(line => MyFunction(line))
var  outFile = Resource.fromFile(outFileName)

outFile.write(processedLines.mkString("\n"))  // severe overhead caused by this line-> processedLines.mkString("\n")
```

( I read on few other forums/blogs that mkString is much [better than other approaches.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447681/merging-a-list-of-strings-using-mkstring-vs-foldright) (eg.)

Is there a better alternative to mkString("\n") ? Is there a totally different approach that would increase my speed of processing files. (remember, I have 50K files of each close to 10K lines).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you are repeating the operation 2 times: Once to iterate over the string and mkString "\n" and then writing these lines to a file. Instead you could do it in one go:

```
for(x <-processedLines){
    outFile.write(x);
    outFile.write("\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm Sorry,but can you please tell me where do I iterate over the string twice ? Also this -  > `Resource.fromFile(outFileName)` returns  a Object on which only write can be used and not writeln().

Comment: @Learner I guess in `processedLines.mkString("\n")` where you iterate over the processedLines to append `\n`. And then next time while writing the new generated long String to file.

Comment: yes, you are right. Got it. Still I don't see any improvements in the output process speed. Commenting write statement, I can say that read are like almost 100X faster than write.This is not normal I would think.

Comment: What type is `outFile`. I mean is it a BufferedWriter or something else? If it doesn't buffer then that takes extra clock ticks.

Comment: I use `scalax.io._` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873802/scalax-io-best-way-to-overwrite-data-in-file | http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.1/api/index.html#scalax.io.Output)and this Resource class. `outFile = Resource.fromFile(outFileName)`. Would bufferedWriter/PrintWriter be much better ? I tried doing the mkString process this line `var processedLines = linesFromGzip(new File(fileName)).map(line => MyFunction(line)).mkString("\n")` but no performance gain. It makes me think this is much of a processor/memory problem rather than i/o problem. What do you think ?

Comment: Well I am not aware of Resource class. But normally in such cases, the bottleneck should be i/o. If its cpu then there is an Issue. Try once with BufferedWriter and compare.

Comment: @Learner YOu might want to try `outFile.writeStrings` instead `outFile.writeStrings(processedLines,"\n")` (http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.3.0/api/scalax/io/SeekableByteChannelResource.html) . But still i think, BufferedWriter should be the fastest way out.

Comment: This is wee bit better, but not as I would expect it to be.Is it the problem with the way I read into an iterator ?

Comment: Do you the use of `BufferedWriter` will improve this drastically ? Because, `bw.write(result.mkString("\n"))`. This part takes the most of the time.

Comment: @Learner Do `for(x <-processedLines){
    bufferedWriter.write(x);
    bufferedWriter.write("\n");
}`

Comment: Better improvements @Jatin.But, I would say the read operation is like  500 files per second. Write is 5 files/second. Can there be a better approach for reading maybe, so that writing becomes faster ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your writing is slower because you are using an `Iterator`. `Iterator`s are lazily evaluated. Actually it is not your writing that is slow, but the evaluation of the `Iteraor`. An `Iterator` is lazily evaluated. This means it gets evaluated in the moment of use. Because you are mapping the elements of your `Iterator` it yields a new `Iterator` that is not evaluated yet. It gets evaluated at the moment you call `mkString`. This function transforms your `Iterator` into a `String`, that is stored in your RAM. To avoid this I recommend using a write function that accepts an `Iterator` as Jatin suggests. You could rewrite his code like:

```
processedLines.foreach(line => {
  outfile.write(line)
  outfile.write("\n")
}
```

This is actually an operation on an `Iterator`. It will evaluate one line at a time and write it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @T.Grotker. This process is bit better over the earlier approaches but not much better I would say.

Comment: Indeed you gain only the performance of only once traversing the Iterator (or String) instead of twice.

Comment: Yes, I would say. would changing the read approach enhance write performance ?

Comment: Yes and no. You would just transfer the calculation from mkString to another point of your programm. This is the best solution I can come up with at the moment.

Comment: Can you elaborate or give some links on what you mean ? Thanks!